# Visual Studio for Mac 2022 ASP.NET Core MVC App Manage NuGet Packages greyed out

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, nuget

I created an ASP.NET Core MVC app using Visual Studio for Mac 2022, but the "Manage NuGet Packages" option is greyed out. I tried a few more templates, and looks like this problem is only with Web and Console Apps.

So far, I've tried:

- cleaning, rebuilding, and closing and reopening the application
- checking if the application is running
- run as Admin

but didn't fix the problem.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Could someone enlighten me with some other possible fixes please?

Thanks.